# Google home speaker dont connect in ubuntu with bluetooh

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, bluetooth-speaker

I am new to this world of Linux distributions, I am trying to connect my Google Home speaker to my Ubuntu PC but it does not connect, the speaker shows in the Bluetooth list but when I try to connect it does not connect.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu PC, but haven't said what Ubuntu product (eg. Ubuntu Desktop?, Ubuntu Server? etc) nor what release of that product (eg. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop?).  LTS releases for example have kernel stack options (newer or older kernels) but we won't know what choices are available to you until you provide details as to what Ubuntu you're using.